# React. Get access to props of a root component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

How can I get access to props of a root  component?

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import cartReducer from './store/cartReducer'
import AddToCart from './cart/addToCart.jsx'

const store = createStore(cartReducer);


render(<Provider store={store}><AddToCart clicked={this.props.onIncrementCounter} />
       </Provider>, document.getElementById('addToCart'));
```

Is it possible? Because I have an error: " Cannot read property 'props' of undefined".
I am new in React.

Here is `AddToCart` component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AddToCart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        items: state.cartItems,
        count: state.cartItemCount
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onIncrementCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddToCart);
```

Comment: have you given props to element where included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got this error " Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" because in that part of your code : `<AddToCart clicked={this.props.onIncrementCounter} />`
`this` is referencing anything

you can try this approach:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import cartReducer from './store/cartReducer'
import AddToCart from './cart/addToCart.jsx'

const store = createStore(cartReducer);


render(<Provider store={store}><AddToCart/>
       </Provider>, document.getElementById('addToCart'));
```

`AddToCart.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AddToCart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div onClick={this.props.onIncrementCounter}>
          Increment
        </div>
      )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        items: state.cartItems,
        count: state.cartItemCount
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onIncrementCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddToCart);
```